# Convert a public key to a string

Tags: android, keystore, public-key-encryption, android-keystore

In my development steps I need to consume an API which requires me to send a RSA public key to it, something like:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBCgKCAQEAsFxynduUThmOU9j7Qg7C/XOKVccJ26AlL/SdEDA1YcFLfG4XcmLm
2rYAq4ia52tIJRuaiDGxaG3EKB38J35ycUe0pB48x+y+rMLDtn/p3PxyfOmkZ+VT
vKN025eNG9MisO+r6dQY8UaODtvRBzov2oB7+sQUD0i2zn7F5BmO86wFxibSk4OG
ssgNyrg6G/H7X/AssgWWtUDV+r4hHRu1aDYJHoNeYTF/nMZl3g9cxuASBOfDemNS
iZPCqiGKuZ3X3tdUBkz/XlkeC+X/tJT9TBEnY2SS4FllHQcMhYaTiKf1ScG3JLbd
ekJCK2fnzXAp/3+Wp0GZD12de/7XLaPMhwIDAQAB
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

For that purpose I use the Keystore API from Android, I do it so:

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(SecurityConstants.KEYSTORE_PROVIDER_ANDROID_KEYSTORE);
        keyStore.load(null);

        String alias = SecurityConstants.KEYSTORE_KEY_ALIAS;

        // Create the keys if necessary
        if (!keyStore.containsAlias(alias)) {

            Calendar notBefore = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar notAfter = Calendar.getInstance();
            notAfter.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
            KeyPairGeneratorSpec spec = new KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(context)
                    .setAlias(alias)
                    .setKeyType(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA)
                    .setKeySize(2048)
                    .setSubject(new X500Principal("CN=test"))
                    .setSerialNumber(BigInteger.ONE)
                    .setStartDate(notBefore.getTime())
                    .setEndDate(notAfter.getTime())
                    .build();
            KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(SecurityConstants.TYPE_RSA, SecurityConstants.KEYSTORE_PROVIDER_ANDROID_KEYSTORE);
            generator.initialize(spec);

            KeyPair keyPair = generator.generateKeyPair();
        }
```

Now the thing is, I have to get the public key as a string and I'm not really sure what's the proper way to do it but I did it like that:

```
public static PublicKey getPublicKey() throws CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableEntryException {
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(SecurityConstants.KEYSTORE_PROVIDER_ANDROID_KEYSTORE);
    keyStore.load(null);
    KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry privateKeyEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry)keyStore.getEntry(SecurityConstants.KEYSTORE_KEY_ALIAS, null);
    return privateKeyEntry.getCertificate().getPublicKey();
}

public static String getPublicKeyAsString() {
    try {
        return "-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\n" + Base64.encodeToString(getPublicKey().getEncoded(), Base64.DEFAULT) +
                "-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----";
    } catch (CertificateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnrecoverableEntryException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I managed to get a string but I'm not sure if that's the way to go, might be not the same exact key that it's supposed to be stored in the keystore, I didn't see Google advocating in doing so. Anyone had that experience?

Comment: try to crypt something with your final string and then try to decrypt with your private key. if it works it should be ok, no?

Comment: That sounds like a way to do it. I'll try it :)

Comment: try storing that in your shared preference , there are encrypted shared preference also available